# Font Suggestions - Need an equally spaced font

Tags: css, graph, fonts

I'm building a CSS/Javascript Graphing engine and one of the components on it is a circular text wheel. I need a font for it that is equally spaced between letters and spaces so that all the labels take up the same amount of space regardless of the letters. Now if I have some letters like 'L' in one of the labels the extra spacing between it in the font I'm using now causes the whole wheel to get offset.

A simple fix for this is to have a font that has equal or almost equal spacing between all letters, spaces and characters.

Any suggestions for me to try out?

As you can see some the wheel is off center because it is smaller than it is most of the time and therefore the diameter is off.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `letter-spacing` property?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a 'monospace' font.  Try Courier or Courier New.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a monospaced font where all of the letters take an equal amount of space.  Here is a collection of web usable monospace fonts to try out:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/monospaced?filter%5Bweb%5D=Y&filter%5Bdownload%5D=all